# In pytorch, what is the difference between indexing with square brackets and "index_select"?

Tags: pytorch, illegalaccessexception, pytorch3d

Say there are two pytorch tensors `a`, which is `float32` with shape `[M, N]`, and `b`, which is `int64` with shape `[K]`. The values in `b` are within [0, M-1], so the following line gives a new tensor `c` indexed by `b`:

```py
c = a[b]    # [K, N] tensor whose i-th row is a[b[i]], with `IndexBackward`
```

However, in a project of mine, this line always reports the following error (which is detected with `torch.autograd.detect_anomaly()`:

```
  with torch.autograd.detect_anomaly():
[W python_anomaly_mode.cpp:104] Warning: Error detected in IndexBackward. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
...
File "/home/user/project/model/network.py", line 60, in index_points
    c = a[b]
 (function _print_stack)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 439, in main
    train_stats = train(
  File "/home/user/project/train_eval.py", line 866, in train
    total_loss.backward()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 147, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: merge_sort: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Note that the line `c = a[b]` above is **not the only** occurrence of said error, but just one among many other lines with square-bracket indexing.

However, the problem magically goes away when I change the indexing style from

```
c = a[b]
```

to

```
c = a.index_select(0, b)
```

I don't understand why indexing with square brackets leads to illegal memory access, but this gives me enough reason to believe square-bracket indexing and `index_select` are implemented differently. Understanding that could be the key to explain this. Also, since the project is rather large and not public, I can't share the exact codes here. You can just treat things above as background and focus on how square-bracket indexing and `index_select` are different. Thanks!

---

Additional information:

- ubuntu 20.04 + cuda 11.2 + RTX3090
- pytorch 1.9.0 + torchvision 1.10.0 + pytorch3d 0.6.0
- The project involves training a network, and the error only occurs when I use the Pulsar renderer from pytorch3d to render something (in fact, anything, even if the rendered data are completely irrelevant to the original code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`torch.index_select` returns a new tensor which copies the indexed fields into a new memory location ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html)).

`torch.Tensor.select` or slicing returns a *view* of the original tensor ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.select.html)).

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to say why this particular difference in functionality might cause the above error.

Comment: Does that mean that you should not use index_select if you need to preserve the gradient graph? I.e. if you're using the selected rows to calculate and return the loss?

Comment: Both tensor-view operations and new tensor allocation operations preserve the gradient graph.

e.g. `c = a.index_select([0,b]) ; c.grad()`  and `c = a[b]; c.grad()` should return the same thing